# XCUITests to check Deeplink / Universal link and the webview loads the url

Tags: objective-c, xcode, wkwebview, xcuitest, xcuielementtypequeryprovider

I am working on an app and wanted to have a XCUITest in place tests that my Deeplink logic works as expected. When a user in their email get a url such as  `http://www.example.com/details?productId=zxy`  the app loads and internally adds a `ref tag =iOSApp_Version_XYN`  to the url and loads it up in WKWebView.

Q1: Is there any way I can add an XCUITests to tests this case? The URL opens the app when I get the url in mail but if I paste this in safari then the app does not load? (not sure why).
Q2: Is there a way to detect via XCUITests what is the url of the webview that is loaded? ( Basically in my url I can confirm that the ref tag is added)

Comment: Does your webview have a URL bar?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: Yuck. Can you share a debugDescription output of the view?

Comment: @MikeCollins -  How could I do that? (The url opens up inside a WKWebView)?

Comment: Hrm. Not sure what the visibility is in an internal web view. Can you try anyway? Set breakpoint, in console `expr print(XCUIApplication().debugDescription)`